# POSIX sh questions (printf and 'read -n')

Tags: bash, sh, posix

I try to write script in POSIX way, without any bashism. And I have faced the following issues that I cannot solve on my own:

1. I know it's a stupid question, but so far I don't quite understand how I can combine these two commands in one.

   ```
    printf ' Port: '
    printf %s "$request" | xmllint --xpath 'string(/Server/Port)' -
   ```

   Is it possible?
2. I have following block in my script:

   ```
    printf '\n\n\nGo? (Y) '
    read -n 1 y
    printf '\n\n'
    case $y in
             y|Y ) printf %s "$request" | xmllint --format - ; printf '\n';;
    esac
   ```

   But, in POSIX `-n` in `read -n 1 y` is undefined. Is it possible to do it in POSIX way?

Comment: Ask two questions in 2 separate questions. Also, what do you mean by "combine" in Q1?

Comment: I think they want something like `echo " Port: $( echo -n "$request" | xmllint --xpath 'string(/Server/Port)' - )"`, but in POSIX rather than Bash.

Comment: @choroba Something like:
printf ' Port: ' %s "$request" | xmllint --xpath 'string(/Server/Port)' -

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex right.

Answer (score 0):

To read 1 character in a POSIX fashion, you can do

```
y=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)
```

(`y=$(head -c 1)` isn't POSIX either.) More info on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464930/can-i-read-a-single-character-from-stdin-in-posix-shell

You can combine

```
printf ' Port: '
printf %s "$request" | xmllint --xpath 'string(/Server/Port)' -
```

with `&&` or `;` or a newline as you have.

Like [chai-t-rex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7208029/chai-t-rex) has pointed out,

```
printf ' Port: %s' "$(printf %s "$request" | xmllint --xpath 'string(/Server/Port)' -)"
```

is also possible, but it doesn't confer any benefit. All it does is slightly reorganize your code while introducing a mild performance pessimization due to starting an unecessary process for the command substitution.